# I can not boot up from an USB stick while I am connected with Intel AMT KVM

Tags: boot, vnc, usb-boot, amt, syslinux

This is very strange. I can not boot up from an USB device until I reboot and close the connection immediately. Then everything works well. I can not provide more information than this, because I don't know more. I don't even know, where I could get logs...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I installed syslinux in stupid mode, it works. Intel AMT KVM is interoperating with the BIOS and breaks something, so it comes to the error.